How do I add a proper description of the spi bus in DTS?
I have a project, where there is a main board with CPU and a daughter board with two e-metering chips, connected to main board with SPI bus. CPU acts as a controller for this bus, it runs on Linux, ARM architecture.
I've been tasked to write a driver (builtin kernel module) for this daughter board, but I have very limited practical experience with SPI linux drivers. This picture shows how my architecture looks. The issue is that different CPU gpios act as Chipselect for each e-meter chip, other "wires" are shared. GPIOS cannot be changed, they are depicted as they are present in schematics.
In Linux spi API, struct spi_device  has a cs_gpio field, but no other fields describing miso/mosi/rst and other gpios, so I guess I have to add a proper description of the spi bus in DTS.
The question is how to do it correctly? Unfortunately, I can't find a proper dts description, or full description of it's fields I may need. The fact that there are two chips makes it even harder :(
Note, that each chip measurements should be written in different sysfs attributes, as they measure electricity from different power lines. This should be implemented in a single driver, so it can't be instantiated twice for each chip, it should run for both of them, not like in this post answers.
I started by implementing a simple spi driver, but I have no idea what values should be in struct spi_board_info  chip_select and bus_num fields, and in  struct spi_device  there is only cs_gpio field, and no fields for describing mosi/miso/rst/sck lines (gpios).
To sum this up, can you please guide me how to write a dts for my daughter board and spi bus, or tell how to instantiate in a driver / dts that spi bus wires are controlled by the exact gpios?

It is unclear which board is master and which board that is slave. Since all SPI buses in your system seem to be point-to-point communication, it isn't obvious.

@Lundin main board is master, e-meter chips are slaves

Please [edit] your question and add more details. What is your hardware? Do you want to implement (1) a kernel driver for your chips or (2) user mode software? You are refering to "a driver implementation". Add a link to this driver or at least specify which driver you mean. Maybe the SPI hardware defines the pins for MISO, MOSI and SCK while you can freely choose any GPIOs as CSx signals if you need CS at all. For (2) see e.g. https://wiki.st.com/stm32mpu/wiki/How_to_use_SPI_from_Linux_userland_with_spidev for (1) look for existing kernel drivers like SPI temperature sensors as an example.

@Bodo By driver implementation I mean linux spi api, my bad. My task is to write a driver. I've edited the post to explain it better.

Does the CPU board have a hardware SPI controller, or do you need to bit-bang everything? Bitbanging can be done, but system performance will be lousy during SPI transfers because a CPU will be tied up timing all the bit transitions.

@IanAbbott In the schematics it very much looks like it's supposed to be bit-banging. There is an SPI controller, but it doesn't connect to the described spi bus in any way. I've edited the post to add two more pictures, screenshots from schematics

You can create a bitbanging SPI controller out of GPIO lines in the device tree, which will use the "spi-gpio" driver in Linux. The details of the device tree node bindings for the controller are documented (in YAML format) at spi-gpio.yaml. You can add child nodes for the two emeter devices. One will have reg = <0>; and the other will have reg = <1>; corresponding to the two CS lines.

It seems you messed up with CS pins. The INT one is (most likely) used as an interrupt by LCD, you can't have the same pin to be bidirectional for two different hardware blocks (it can be for a single one, like i2c). Or there is no LCD connected? I didn't get this...

If this is the V3X CPU, then it does have a spi controller.  There is also user space SPI and GPIO that you can manually select the chip selects.  Everything requires sane hardware.

@0andriy no LCD is connected in this board. Many gpios are used in a way different from what was intended by allwinner :) So in this configuration these pins are used as a standalone spi controller

So thanks to @IanAbbott I found out about spi-gpio driver in Linux (src), and device tree binding description here.
So this is a proper device tree:
spi-gpio {
    compatible = "spi-gpio";
    #address-cells = <0x1>;
    ranges;
    status = "okay";

    sck-gpios   = <&pio 4 9 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;  // PE9
    mosi-gpios  = <&pio 4 6 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;  // PE6
    miso-gpios  = <&pio 4 8 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;  // PE8
    cs-gpios    = <&pio 4 4 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>,  // PE4
                  <&pio 4 17 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>; // PE17
    num-chipselects = <2>;

    /* Clients */
    m90e32@0 {
        reg = <0>;
        compatible = "atmel,m90e32";
        spi-max-frequency = <950000>;
    };

    m90e32@1 {
        reg = <1>;
        compatible = "atmel,m90e32";
        spi-max-frequency = <950000>;
    };
};

The idea is to use spi-gpio driver to communicate with e-meter chips, it can be done via spidev in userspace or in a different kernel module. More info in my other question.
